# Is there a way to not use an item from a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I've learned that typing

```
using namespace std;
```

at the beginning of a program is a bad habit, because it includes every function in the namespace. This risks causing errors if there is a name collision.

My question is, does there exist a way to specify which namespace functions you *don't* want to use? Is there some statement, such as

```
not_using std::cin;
```

that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do that (include everything and then selectively exclude something).

Your options are:

1) always explicitly qualify names. Like `std::vector<int> v;`

2) pull in all names with `using namespace std;`

3) pull in just the names you need with, for example, `using std::vector;` and then do `vector<int> v;` - names other than "vector" are not pulled in.

Note: `using namespace std;` doesn't have to go at global scope and pollute the entire file. You can do it inside a function if you want:

```
void f() {
    using namespace std;
    // More code
}
```

That way, only `f()` pulls in all names in its local scope. Same goes for `using std::vector;` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can `using ns_name::name;` just the name's you want unqualified access to.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global namespace scope, use this syntax :
For example :
std::cout :

For more examples read this :
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/